# How to find which tableview is editing in textFieldDidEndEditing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using 2 `tableviews`

both have `textfiled` in `tableviewcell`,

I am getting text of textfield in `textFieldDidEndEditing` but how would i know text is being editing belongs to which tableview ,i just want to know the condition where i can differentiate text coming from textfield to store in two different array.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
  //  let indexOf = txtArray.index(of:textField.tag)

    if self.tblAnswer.isEditing
    {
        let indexOf = textField.tag

        if let text = textField.text
        {
            if allAnsText.indices.contains(indexOf)
            {
                allAnsText.remove(at: indexOf)
            }
            if text.isEmpty
            {
                print("Write some text there")
            }
            else
            {
            allAnsText.insert(text, at: indexOf)
            print(allAnsText)
            }
        }
    }
    else if self.tblVideo.isEditing
    {
        let indexOf = textField.tag

        if let text = textField.text
        {
            if allMediaText.indices.contains(indexOf)
            {
                allMediaText.remove(at: indexOf)
            }
            if text.isEmpty
            {
                print("Write some text there")
            }
            else
            {
                allMediaText.insert(text, at: indexOf)
                print(allMediaText)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show some codes what you have tried.

Comment: your tableviewcell is different or same for both tableview

Comment: What are you getting textField.superView.superView ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik diffrent tableviewcell

Comment: If you don't want to use superview only way is Fix some constant for Tableview 1 and tableview 2 , let say for tableview 1 is 5000 and tableview 2 it is 6000, Now in cell for row give tag like 5000 / 6000 + indexPath.row , and `textFieldDidEndEditing` method check tag > 6000 it is tableview 2

Comment: you can check super view of your textfield. yourTextField.superView.superView

Comment: Salman has already ans regarding this approach. Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about traversing the view hierarchy; it is error prone and the exact details may change in the future (and break your app horribly).

#### Original Answer (for posterity)

Instead, try this:

1. Get the text field's location on screen:

   ```
   // Center on text field's own coordinate system
   let position = textField.frame.center

   // Center on Window's coordinate system
   let positionOnWindow = textField.convert(position, to: nil)
   ```
2. Convert that point to the table view's coordinate system, and see if it corresponds to a row:

   ```
   let positionInTable = tableView1.convert(positionOnWindow, from: nil)</strike>

   if let indexPath = tableView1.indexPathForRow(at: positionInTable) {
       // Text field is inside a row of table view 1
   } else {
       // Otherwise
   }
   ```

**Note:** Code above is untested. May contain compiler errors.

Assuming both code snippets run on the same class (your table view delegate, data source and text field delegate) there should be no problem passing the value of `positionOnWindow` around (it can all happen inside the text field delegate method).

#### Better Answer

As duly pointed by @rmaddy in the comments, the code above is **too roundabout**; you can directly get the position with:

```
let positionInTable = tableView1.convert(textField.frame.center, from: textField)
```

*(no need the trip to the window's coordinate system and back)*

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Let me know if you got it to work (I haven't tested my answer's code).

Comment: finally.thanks for efforts @Nicolas Miari(special thanks),@Pallavi Srikhakollu,@Salman Ghumsani,@Jon Snow

Comment: This is more complicated than needed. Just do: `let positionInTable = tableView1.convert(textField.frame.center, from: textField)`.

Comment: @rmaddy You are correct. I’ll update this answer as soon as I get to my desk.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x**

Assuming your hierarchy of textFiled is:

*TextField->Cell->TableView*

Write this line of code in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
print(textField.superview?.superview)
if textField.superview?.superview == myTable1 {

}
else if textField.superview?.superview == myTable2 {

}
else {

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `else if` or directly `else` instead, Here two if is meaningless

Comment: Isn't there the cell's **content view** in between the text field and the cell? Internal structure of `UITableView` and `UITableviewCell` are implementation details, not part of the public API. Code that relies on that structure is very fragile.

Comment: This is not the correct way. This makes bad assumptions about the private layout of a cell class and the table view class.